# Bibtex: empty publisher in reference key

Tags: bibtex

I have bibtex file with TOO MANY citations. When compiling the document, it gives in error saying empty publisher in `{key}` for almost all of the entries in my `bib` file. I used the same bib file for preparing document for another journal and there were no complaints. However, when using the SAGE latex [template](https://us.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_4.zip) from this [website](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/manuscript-submission-guidelines#PreparingYourManuscript) it gives so many of these errors.

I am using the `\documentclass[Review,sageapa,times]{sagej}` at the top and `\bibliographystyle{mslapa}` before supplying bibtex file using `\bibliography{refer.bib}`, the only change from template. Is there a way to ignore all those warnings that are appearing without manually adding publisher for those limitless entries?

[image]

Comment: all these are ignorable warnings, but there are too many of them.